# Error while comparing vlaues in two objects

Tags: java

I want to compare the values calculated by maxMarks method in betterResult() method and return and print the higher maxmark.I am getting an error while doing so. Also ignore some other methods(in class Result)that i have created as they are for later use.

```
public class Result {

int[] marks;

    public int maxMarks(int[] marks) {
        int max = marks[0];
        for (int i = 0; i < marks.length - 1; i++) {
            if (marks[i] > max) {
                max = marks[i];
            }

        }
        System.out.println(max);
        return max;

    }
    public double averageMarks(int[] marks) {
        double avg;
        double sum = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < marks.length; i++) {
            sum = sum + marks[i];
        }
        avg = sum / marks.length;
        System.out.println(avg);
        return avg;
    }


    public int total(int[] marks) {
        int total = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < marks.length; i++) {

            total = total + marks[i];

        }
        return total;

    }


}
```

Second class:

```
public class TestResult {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        TestResult result = new TestResult();

        result.display();

    }

    public void display() {
        TestResult result1 = new TestResult();
        Result res1 = new Result();
        res1.maxMarks(new int[] {45, 56, 88, 42, 76  });
        Result res2 = new Result();
        res2.maxMarks(new int[] { 60, 70, 78, 55, 40 });
        result1.betterResult(res1, res2);
    }

    public Result betterResult(Result res1, Result res2) {
        if (res1 > res2)
            return res1;
        else
            return res2;

    }
}
```

Error:

```
Error in betterResult "bad operand types for binary operator '>'"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if (res1 > res2)
```

You are trying to compare to object of types Result. You can not do that. What is the meaning of res1 > res2 ? Which values shoudl be checked ?

You can add a `greaterThan` method in your Result class for example :

```
public boolean greaterThan(Result res2) {
   // do somtheing to compare this to res2
}
```

Or you can implement the `Comparable` interface

Answer (score 0):

You're comparing two objects without a comparator:

```
 public Result betterResult(Result res1, Result res2) {
        if (res1 > res2)
            return res1;
        else
            return res2;

    }
```

Your method doesn't know how to compare two objects, they're not integers or some primitive types to compare straightforward.

You can change your method to something like this:

```
 public Result betterResult(Result res1, Result res2) {
            if (res1.value1 > res2.value1)
                return res1;
            else
                return res2;

        }
```

Or Implement Comparable interface and use it when comparing your objects:

```
private class ResultsComparator implements Comparator<Result> {
        public int compare(Result res1, Result res2) {
            if (res1.value1 > res2.value1)
                    return res1;
                else
                    return res2;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You cannot compare two objects directly using `>` operand. I changed
   your code so the Result class implements Comparable to compare
   objects with their maxMark() result.
2. There is no need to create two instance of the Result class because the `int[] marks` instance variable is not used, so I created a parametrized constructor to initialize the array.

   ```
   public class Result implements Comparable{
      private int[] marks;

      public Result(int[] marks){
         this.marks = marks;
      }

      public int maxMarks() {
       int max = marks[0];
       for (int i = 0; i < marks.length - 1; i++) {
           if (marks[i] > max) {
               max = marks[i];
           }

       }
       System.out.println(max);
       return max;

      }
      public double averageMarks() {
         double avg;
         double sum = 0;
          for (int i = 0; i < marks.length; i++) {
              sum = sum + marks[i];
          }
          avg = sum / marks.length;
          System.out.println(avg);
          return avg;
      }


      public int total() {
          int total = 0;
          for (int i = 0; i < marks.length; i++) {
              total = total + marks[i];
          }
          return total;
      }

      public int compareTo(Object o){
          Result secondResult = (Result)o;
          return this.maxMark()-secondResult.maxMark();
      }

    }

      public class TestResult{


          public static void main(String args[]) {
              TestResult result = new TestResult();
              result.display();
          }

          public void display() {
              TestResult result1 = new TestResult();
              Result res1 = new Result(new int[] {45, 56, 88, 42, 76  });
              int maxMark1 = res1.maxMarks();//you can remove this line
              Result res2 = new Result(new int[] { 60, 70, 78, 55, 40 });
              int maxMark2 = res2.maxMarks();//you can remove this line
              result.betterResult(res1,res2);
          }

          public Result betterResult(Result res1, Result res2) {
              if (res1.compareTo(res2) > 0)
                return res1;
              else
                return res2;
          }   
    }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have 2 problems

1. You didn't understand how static Classes work differently than Instanciable ones
2. You are trying 2 compare 2 non Primitive objects

Right now, your Result Class, provides methods that should/could work as static, but in the same time, you are instantiating Result objects.

Now if you want to compare 2 Results instances, you should alter your class, sou you can actualy use/keep that marks[] variable

```
public Result(int[] marks){
    this.marks = marks
}

//Notice, I've removed the int[] marks property, we'll use the local variable instead
public int maxMarks() {

    int max = marks[0];
    for (int i = 0; i < marks.length - 1; i++) {
        if (marks[i] > max) {
            max = marks[i];
        }

    }
    System.out.println(max);
    return max;
}
```

Then, this would work :

```
 public void display() {
    Result result1 = null;// this will point to the greatest Result, that betterResult will return
    Result res1 = new Result(new int[] {45, 56, 88, 42, 76  });
    Result res2 = new Result(new int[] { 60, 70, 78, 55, 40 });
    result1 = betterResult(res1, res2);
}

 public Result betterResult(Result res1, Result res2) {
    res1.maxMarks() > res2.maxMarks() ? return res1 : return res2;

 }
```